# How to initialize an observable backed by a BehaviorSubject on first call?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have an Observable that is backed by a private BehaviorSubject. On the first emit, I would like to initialize the BehaviorSubject from an async call, but I can't come up with a great pattern to do so. As far as I can tell, BehaviorSubjects can't be initialized from an async function.

What I have so far is:

```
protected _monkeyNames = new BehaviorSubject<Set<string>>(null);

MonkeyNames$: Observable<Set<string>> = this._monkeyNames.pipe(
  switchMap(async (nodes) => nodes ?? (await this.getMonkeyNames()))
);

protected async getMonkeyNames(): Promise<Set<string>> {
  const names = new Set(await this.stateService.getMonkeyNames());
  return names;
}
```

But this won't set the BehaviorSubject, it will only be set when I call `setMonkeyNames` later to save a new value. If I do call `.next()` inside of `getMonkeyNames`, the Observable will emit again, which could result in an eternal loop if `names` is `null`.

It might be my own ignorance when it comes to rxjs, but does anyone have a pattern they use for this?

Edit:
I should mention that this is a service, and I won't have access to `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 1):

`BehaviorSubject` is useful only when there is a initial value. Since you don't have any, `ReplaySubject` or `Subject` can be used. Also initializing BehaviorSubject with null, when type clearly restricts to Set<...>, is just an error.

If your service returns promise of some value, convert it to Observable with `from` and process in operator chain.

```
monkeyNames$: Observable<Set<string>> = from(this.stateService.getMonkeyNames())
.pipe(
map(names=> new Set(names))
)
```

Comment: It isn't an error when setting it as a type `BehaviorSubject <Set<string>|null>(null)`

Comment: How would I update the observable when monkey names are added though? From what I understand this would only emit once.I would need to use ReplaySubject, which has the same problem of initializing.

Comment: you can initialize it to `null`, then use a filter to ignore `null`. then in the `ngOninit()` do the actual initialization of the subject with real data.

Comment: Create `Subject` that emits changes, then `merge` it with initial data and optionally `scan` to apply changes.

Comment: @Get Off My Lawn. Yes, it's ok to initialize with `null` if `BehaviorSubject` is typed for such value. But rxjs library has many operators to do it in more straightforward and cleaner way than declaring a variable of type that is not intended to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is initialize the `BehaviorSubject` with an empty `Set`, then do the api call or async call in the constructor of the service that would set the initial value for the first time.

```js
protected _monkeyNames = new BehaviorSubject<Set<string>>(new Set());

MonkeyNames$: Observable<Set<string>> = this._monkeyNames.asObservable();

protected async getMonkeyNames(): Promise<Set<string>> {
  const names = new Set(await this.stateService.getMonkeyNames());
  this._monkeyNames.next(names);
  return names;
}

constructor() {
  this.getMonkeyNames();
}
```

Example HTML Template:

```html
<div *ngIf="MonkeyNames$ | async as names">
  <div *ngFor="let name of names">{{ name }}</div>
</div>
```

Here is a working [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/behaviorsubject-from-async?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) (with some extra debugging; see console).

Comment: Apologies, I should have specified this is a service. I don't believe I'll have access to `ngOnInit()` in a service.

Comment: I have updated the answer and Stackblitz example as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attempting to initialize the subject, maybe you can declare your `MonkeyNames$` from two different sources using `merge`:

```js
protected _monkeyNames = new Subject<Set<string>>();

MonkeyNames$: Observable<Set<string>> = merge(
    from(this.getMonkeyNames()),
    this._monkeyNames
).pipe(
    shareReplay(1)
);
```

Comment: subscribing to this at a later time would not give you access to the current state.

Comment: Good point.  We probably need a `shareReplay(1)` in there.